# what is {% block content %} and {% endblock content %} for in Django?

Tags: python, django

so I just started reading a book on Django (for beginners) and I came across the following code snipet:

```
<header>

<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a> | <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>

</header>

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Could anyone possibly explain to me what is the use of `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock content %}`? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to keep reading. Seriously, this question is too broad for StackOverflow format but it should be explained later in that book. Alternatively you can refer to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#block

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`block` is used for overriding specific parts of a template.

In your case, you have a block named `content` and this is supposed to be overridden by children that inherit from this template.

From the examples at [The Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

Template to be extended, named `base.html`

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

Overriding Child template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}My amazing blog{% endblock %}
```

"My amazing site" will be overriden by the child and then display "My amazing blog"

Answer (score 25):

That's where the power of the templates comes from in a sense.

You can create a hierarchy of templates so start with `base.html` which might be like you've got above;

```
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
```

Then you can create any other template, `home.html` for example, and do something like;

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>This is the home page</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Then you'd reference `home.html` in django and it'd include the markup from `base.py` with the content defined in `home.html`.

That's the basics, but if you put some templates together using blocks you'll pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you have code excerpts from 2 files:

base.html:

```
<body bgcolor="cyan">

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
    
</body>
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Hello World from Abhishek</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

here in **home.html**, the attributes of **base.html** will be extended but by using  `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}` you will be able to override the code block of **home.html** upon the attributes of **base.html**

This is **Jinja** template for a dynamic website.

Answer (score 1):

That is simply django’s template inheritance. It basically means that a block of content from another html file has been imported into that html file you’re currently on.