# Why isn't my CSS, Javascipt, and bootstrap not showing up in my django site?

Tags: python, css, django

I'm using the Djanog for beginners book, it tells me to just copy and paste but when I do so, it doesn't work. The functionalities work(login, logout, etc) it's just the book shows the website being updated and looking way better than mine.

Here's my base.html file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81i
uXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>{% block title %}Newspaper App{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Newspaper</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu"
data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
aria-expanded="false">
{{ user.username }}
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
aria-labelledby="userMenu">
<a class="dropdown-item"
href="{% url 'password_change'%}">Change password</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">
Log Out</a>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
{% else %}
<form class="form-inline ml-auto">
<a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
Log In</a>
<a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">
Sign up</a>
</form>
{% endif %}
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4\
YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/popper.min.js"
integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAKl8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Other HTML files:

Signup.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
Wassup {{ user.username }}!
<p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
{% else %}
<p>You Are Not Logged In MAN</p>
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> |
<a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

login.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Log In{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Log In</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

NOTE: login.html is in another directory called "registration" which is in my templates directory.

The book doesn't even tell me to download Bootstrap(even if i'm a beginner, I feel like I should download Bootstrap for it to work). If anyone knows what the issue is please help.

Comment: No there is no need of downloading bootstrap you can use it via CDN. Which file is not looking good **base.html** or other file ?. There is a problem with your bootstrap CDN you have one ```\```(back slash) inside your CDN remove that it will work

Comment: I'm not 100% on which file is the problem, although i'm pretty sure it's the base.html file, because I haven't changed anything else(on the topic of bootstrap). Could you point out where in my code the "\" is in? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: ```<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/\
bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81i\
uXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO">``` this one have issue and this one is correct ```<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/
bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81i
uXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO">``` replace CDN with this one

Comment: If you are extending your **base.html** than you have to use django teamplate ```{% block body %}```  refer this doc for more info. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#templates

Comment: Like I said I just copy and pasted the code in so i'm not sure if anything is wrong or not. If extending my base.html file means that another HTML file has the tag {% extends 'base.html' %}, then I should put {% block body %} at the top of my base.html file?

Comment: No not on the top of your **base.html**. Did you followed tutorial properly check I think you're missing something please check video tutorials on Django templates how to block certain content and and use different content like you've did for tittle you're changing your title of page on different pages.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383660/14457833

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean I think. So it's like when I write  {%  block content %} and {% endblock content %} to override something? If it's not that then I'm not really sure what else it could be. My problem is that I don't know WHERE to put the command your talking about. If it's not to much to ask could you rewrite my code and tell me whats wrong with it and what you changed in order for it to work?

Comment: for that I want to know how you are extending your **base.html** in your other html please provide any one html page where you extending **base.html**

Comment: I edited my question, hope it helps!

Comment: Hii @fatbrokekid check I've edited your **base.html** just replace my code with your **base.html** and let me know if it's working or not

Comment: It worked! But there is a problem, when I click on the dropbox, it doesn't work. Like it doesn't show the options to "change password" and "logout". In the book it shows that it should work. Could you help me find the problem?

Comment: which book you are reading let me know

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem is in integrity attribute it contains wrong SRI hash so it's failed to load from the resource server just copy given code and try if it's working or not

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %}Newspaper App{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Newspaper</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ user.username }}
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change'%}">Change password</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">
                            Log Out</a>
                    </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
            {% else %}
            <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                    Log In</a>
                <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">
                    Sign up</a>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and if you stuck anywhere you can follow bootstrap official [doc.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)